# Send mail in Background for gmail id have 2-layer security

Tags: android, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send mail in background using the method provided in the accepted answer of [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a). Earlier the mails were sending easily. But due to new gmail's 2-step verification, the I am not able to send mail from email id having this feature. Please suggest any method or change in the code by which I can send mail through the mail id having the 2-step verification.

Thanks.

Comment: @Downvoters : at-least add a reason for down voting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 2 Step security, you will need to generate an application specific password, and use that from your app.

[This Link](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens?hl=en) will bring you to the creation page for new application specific passwords.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is there any other method to do this? Because all the users of the app will have to generate a new password for the app.

Comment: This is why two layer security exists, so that a user will have to do this, so they know was is accessing their account.